# If Current Domain is X, Then Include

Tags: php

I'm trying to use some basic code to include a file if the current domain is http://example.com

How do I do this?

```
if (...){
include("../clicky.php");
}
```

Comment: Have you investigated the `$_SERVER` super-global?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)** can help in many ways

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="example.com")
{
      include("whatever");
}
```